# How to kill 3rd party process in android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, android-mapview, android-maps

My application will launch 3rd party map activity and set the place. Once user press back from Map activity, it will return to previous activity.

Once i quit the application, the map activity and other process will be keep running. i would like to close them. How should i do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you want to close them? The OS handles that.

Answer (score 1):

Try Launching the foreign activity with FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY

A process is not the same as an Activity, and it's not your concern if a process (even your own) remains alive when not in use, as Android will dispose of it when appropriate.

You should never try to kill foreign processes (you can't anymore anyway), and the situations where you want to kill or end your own are rare (mostly for testing to make sure you can recover).